# After LifeTime - Session.php Auto Logout

Tags: laravel, session, lifetime

When i log out using the button, i update an attribute (isActive)  in the User Table. Everything works, except when the lifetime finish.
Why?

Use of this data is strictly informative. So a simple development goes more than good.

Thank you

Session.php

```
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

AuthenticateUsers.php

```
    public function logout(Request $request)
{
    User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['isActive' => '0']);

    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really get your question but here is my try to give you hints about what's going on.

What you have to understand I think is that when the lifetime time is passed, the client may not be anymore on your website since a long time so nothing special will happen. There will be no action taken on the client, and no action taken on the server. Simply because there is no way to detect and no (simple) way to execute code without an associated request.

The only thing that happen is that on the next request with that cookie, which may or may not happen, laravel will detect that the lifetime passed and will consider the cookie as invalid (and consider the associated request as a non loggued request)

Your logout route is called when the user specifically ask for a disconnect. It'll not be magically called when a session is invalidated because laravel does't detect invalidation of session without getting a request from that session. Also once (and if) invalidation is detected, laravel will not call logout route because the user will be already logged out (session is invalid, so data can't be trusted and used).

What way to do what you want is to store the last action of the user (that is, update it evertime he do a request) and consider as inactive all user where last action is more than X min ago. Beware that it's highly unreliable but it's a quite good estimate.

If you really want some sort of reliable way, take a look at that question: [Detect user exit site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885544/detect-user-exit-site) but please note that polling users periodically will have a very high performance cost for your servers.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly fails? Is the `users`-table not updated when the lifetime-session expires?

That's because this happens automatically by setting the lifetime of the session cookie. When the cookie expires this doesn't call the `logout` route in your app and doesn't update the `users`-table.

I think the only way to accomplish that, is by setting the lifetime to a very high number of minutes (eg. `99999999` => `190 years`) and "forcing" the user to hit the logout button.
But a user can still just close the browser window and leave your app without logging out.

Comment: Good solution....
I have to understand if it really is worth it or to study another solution!
Thank you!